# How to limit the size of a python logging log file?

Tags: python, logging

Consider the following sample code:

```
import logging
import time
from logging.handlers import RotatingFileHandler
#----------------------------------------------------------------------
def create_rotating_log(path):
    """
    Creates a rotating log
    """    
    logger = logging.getLogger("Rotating Log")
    logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

    # add a rotating handler
    handler = RotatingFileHandler(path, maxBytes=20,
                                      backupCount=1)
    logger.addHandler(handler)

    for i in range(20):
        logger.info("This is test log line %s" % i)
        time.sleep(1.5)
    
#----------------------------------------------------------------------
if __name__ == "__main__":
    log_file = "test.log"
    create_rotating_log(log_file)
```

After the script is finished with `backupCount=1`, it creates two files `test.log` and `test.log.1` where the first file has contains:

`This is test log line 19`

and the second one conatins:

`This is test log line 18`

I don't want any backup files and I also want to limit the size of my log file. So, when I set `backupCount=0` the logger just appends every line in the log file as if there is no limit to the size on log file. This is the contents of `test.log` with `backupCount=0`:

```
This is test log line 0
This is test log line 1
This is test log line 2
This is test log line 3
This is test log line 4
This is test log line 5
This is test log line 6
This is test log line 7
This is test log line 8
This is test log line 9
This is test log line 10
This is test log line 11
This is test log line 12
This is test log line 13
This is test log line 14
This is test log line 15
This is test log line 16
This is test log line 17
This is test log line 18
This is test log line 19
```

Comment: Why do you want to limit the size of your log file? From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.handlers.html#logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler) it looks like you can use the rotating file handler with either 1 logfile unbounded or multiple logfiles that are bounded. So whats the behavior that you want to happen?

Comment: @steviestickman is it possible to get 1 bounded logfile?

Comment: maybe, but rotating file handler is not the handler you can use for this purpose. Thats why i am asking why you want to constrain yourself to 1 file and what behaviour you expect from such a handler.

Comment: @steviestickman The reason is that one of our API is generating logs of 100s of gigabytes daily.